# MySQl Query with DECLARE and IF Else causing error

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am converting mssql query to MysQL, but i am getting number of error like Declare is not at right position and IF ELSE it not at right position. below is my sql query:

```
declare v_StartDateIn varchar(25) default '@1'
declare v_EndDateIn varchar(25)   default '@2'

IF (v_StartDateIn = '') OR (v_StartDateIn is null) OR (v_StartDateIn = '$1') THEN SET v_StartDateIn = concat(left(DATE_FORMAT (NOW(), 126),7),'-01T00:00:00');
END IF;

IF (v_EndDateIn = '') OR (v_EndDateIn is null) OR (v_EndDateIn = '$2') THEN SET v_EndDateIn  = timestampadd(Month,1,v_StartDateIn);
END IF;

declare v_StartDate datetime(3) default date_format(v_StartDateIn,126);
declare v_EndDate datetime(3) default date_format(v_EndDateIn,126);

declare v_Limit varchar(20) default 'Limit';

SELECT
 concat(left(date_format(sl.StartStateDate,120),4)
 ,' ',
 left(date_format(sl.StartStateDate,107),3)
 ,' ',
 substring(date_format(sl.StartStateDate,120),9,2)) as Date
,Left(format(sl.StartStateDate,'D'),3) as Day
,substring(date_format(sl.StartStateDate,120),12,5) as Start
,substring(date_format(sl.EndStateDate,120),12,5) as End

FROM DataLogs sl
WHERE 1=1
and sl.StartStateDate >= v_StartDate
and sl.EndStateDate   <  v_EndDate
```

Can someone help me how to use above query in MySQL.

Comment: causing error? what error?

Answer (score 0):

- DECLARE

You can substitute it with a session variable:

```
SET @v_StartDateIn = 'value';
```

- IF-THEN-ENDIF

It is a problem for MySQL script. All these (IF, CASE, LOOP...) flow control statements cannot be used in script. They can be used in source objects only [stored procedures/functions, triggers, events].